# How to use bash variables in a awk command within bash for

Tags: bash, shell, awk, for

I want to use a set of previous variables created to filter columns of a file called a.ped_snps.temp with awk within bash for loop.

For this, I created bash variables: var_i_1, var_i_2, ... var_i_n_blocks to be the lower bound; and var_f_1, var_f_2, ... var_f_n_blocks to be upper bound.

Note that n_blocks afore mentioned is the number of files that will be created with the columns delimeted by var_i_1 and var_f_1, and so on.
I used the follow script:

```
n_blocks=$(wc -l "a.temp" | awk '{print $1}') # number of blocks to be created, a.temp is the file with the number of blocks

for i in $(seq 1 1 $n_blocks)            # to iterate of first to n_blocks 
    do
    awk -v v_i="$var_i_$i" -v v_f="$var_f_$i" '{     # to declare variables of lower ($var_i_$i) and upper ($var_f_$i) bounds for each iteraction to awk command
    for (i=v_i;i<=v_f;i++) {printf (i==1?"":FS)$i}; print ""     # for statement to print all comlumns between specified in v_i and v_f variables in each iteraction
    }' <a.ped_snps.temp > block_$i.txt       # print one txt file with each block for each iteraction
done
```

This code runs and give the files in correct number of iteractions specified in for command, however, only the first column is printed in the output of each file.

When a I used only the awk (as below) with var_i_1 and var_f_1 bash variables (with vaules 2 and 4, respectively, previously stored) the output (block_1.txt) contains only the columns $2, $3 and $4, wich is desired, and so on for the other blocks.

```
awk -v v_i="$var_i_1" -v v_f="$var_f_1" '{     # declare variables of lower ($var_i_1) and upper ($var_f_1) bounds for first block (set of cloumns)
    for (i=v_i;i<=v_f;i++) {printf (i==1?"":FS)$i}; print ""     # for statement to print only comlumns between specified in v_i and v_f variables for first block
}' <a.ped_snps.temp > block_1.txt       # print one txt file only with a set of columns specified in v_i and v_f variables
```

So, someone can help me to implement this code in a bash for? In summary, I want to use bash variables previously created in a awk command within bash for.

I hope that I was clear in my explantion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running a loop around `awk` is a sign that you should probably rethink what you're doing and rewrite your script in awk alone (or awk plus a much simpler sh wrapper).    Looping around awk and wanting to mix in shell code & variables is a good sign that you should rewrite your script in perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are expecting `$var_i_$i` to expand to the value of `$var_i_1`, `$var_i_2` and so on - unfortunately it doesn't. To illustrate, suppose we set

```
$ var_i_1=23; var_i_2=45; var_i_3=67
```

then

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 3); do awk -v v_i="$var_i_$i" 'BEGIN{print v_i}'; done
1
2
3
```

What's happening here is that the shell parses `$var_i_$i` as `$var_i_` *concatenated with* `$i`. Since `$var_i_` is likely unset/empty, `v_i` and `v_f` simply inherit the value of the loop index `i`.

There are ugly ways of doing the kind of indirection that you want, e.g.

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 3); do awk -v v_i="$(eval echo \${var_i_$i})" 'BEGIN{print v_i}'; done
23
45
67
```

however since bash supports arrays, a cleaner solution would be to use arrays for your `var_i` and `var_f` values, ex.

```
$ var_i=(23 45 67)
```

then (remembering that arrays are zero-indexed)

```
$ for i in $(seq 0 2); do awk -v v_i="${var_i[i]}" 'BEGIN{print v_i}'; done
23
45
67
```

Comment: I solved the problem with you tip, thanks.